# Copying files with concurrent.futures raising AttributeError (silently)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Edit: Figured out the reason... Apparently local function definition is not allowed when using concurrent.futures. Moving copy_files out of download_files function solved it.

---

I'm having trouble copying files with parallel processes, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
When I try to run it I get the following message printed out:
`Done copying file <Future at 0x257d8f1ea70 state=finished raised AttributeError>` printed out, but no exception.

I have commented out the code I'm trying to run, and replaced it with equivalent (or so I though) non parallel execution, which works. What gives?

```
def download_files(directories: set, path_tuples: set) -> os.path:
    """Copies the files"""
    def copy_file(_path_tuple: tuple):
        from_path, to_path = _path_tuple
        try:
            shutil.copy(from_path, to_path)
            return to_path

        except PermissionError:
            print(f"Tried to copy file from {from_path} to {to_path}, but was denied access")
        
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f"Tried to copy file from {from_path} to {to_path}, but invalid path!")

    print(f"Found {len(path_tuples)} files to copy, in {len(directories)}")

    for directory in directories:
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            print(f"Local directory didn't exist, create it")
            try:
                os.mkdir(directory)
            except PermissionError:
                print(f"Tried to make folder at {directory}, but was denied access")
            except FileNotFoundError:
                print(f"Tried to make folder at {directory}, but invalid path!")
                
    if path_tuples:
        
        # with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        #     results = {executor.submit(copy_file, path_tuple) for path_tuple in path_tuples}
        #
        #     for target_path in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
        #         print(f"Done copying file {target_path}")
        
        for path_tuple in path_tuples:
            copy_file(path_tuple)
```

Comment: A ``Future`` eventually *contains* the result or exception. Instead of printing the ``Future``, fetch the exception! Use ``target_path.result()`` or ``target_path.exception()`` to forcefully/gracefully get the exception.

Comment: then I get `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'download_files.<locals>.copy_file'` when I do `for target_path in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
    target_path.result()`
The exception is caused by the path.result() command. If I remove it, I get no exceptions, but also no files are copied.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the reason... Apparently local function definition is not allowed when using concurrent.futures. Moving copy_files out of download_files function solved it.